# strcmp ignoring accents, outputs false

Tags: c, string, compare, strcmp

I have a couple of strcmp's to get a boolean and all of them work fine except if the string contains an accent.

```
if(strcmp(arrayOfStrings[index], "Día de descanso") == 0
```

Outputs false instead of true. I've been trying to compare using escape sequences but I can't make it work.

Strings are added to arrayOfStrings with the next function:

```
void introducirPlan()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    printf("Actividad del dia %d? ", i);
    scanf(" %[^\n]", diasEntrenamiento[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

There another function just to check the strings added using strcmp:

```
bool compararDescanso(int idia)
{
  if(strcmp(diasEntrenamiento[idia], "Día de descanso") == 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  if(strcmp(diasEntrenamiento[idia], "Dia de descanso") == 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

It looks like strcmp outputs false here:

```
  while(cntImprEntr <= 10)
  {
    if(compararDescanso(cntImprEntr) == true)
    {
      printf(" D "); /*"D" never gets printed if string contains accent */
      columna++;
      dia++;
    }
    else
    {
      printf(" C ");
      columna++;
      dia++;
    }
    if(columna == 5)
    {
      printf("|");
    }
    printf(" ");
    cntImprEntr++;
    if(columna >= 7)
    {
      printf("\n");
      columna = 0;
    }
  }
```

Is there any way I can make strcmp not ignore the accent and give true output? When the string inside the index contains "Dia" instead of "Día" it works fine.
Thanks

Comment: Try unicode strings.

Comment: [mcve] is needed. We don't know what your array is containing.

Comment: Thing is, when the string compared is exactly "Día" as stated above, strcmp still outputs false. Rest of array contains random strings.

Comment: We need it to be proven with [mcve], as asked already. Without it the question will get closed soon.

Comment: @jgam Thing is, issue could be in the string itself which you have stored in  `arrayOfStrings[index], could you please prepare a mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added more details in order to help understand the whole situation.

Comment: You've not shown  byte-by-byte dumps of the two strings, which is the only way to demonstrate what result `strcmp()` should be returning.  There are different ways of representing accented characters in UTF-8 — sometimes as a single composite character (one code point), sometimes as a base character with the accent as a modifier (using two code points).  Two such strings showing the same glyph would not compare equal.  You must know which code set you're working in, too.  But a good start would be an unambiguous dump of the two strings that you think should be equal.

Comment: A [mcve] might not be sufficient by itself, because there are other factors involved, such as the source and execution character encodings of the program, and the character encoding of the program's user input. The source and execution character encodings may be controllable using compiler options. For GCC, those would be the `-finput-charset=` option (for the source code character encoding) and the `-fexec-charset=` option (for the executable character encoding). You may also need to set the terminal to the correct locale and call `setlocale`, although `strcmp` doesn't care about the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is linked to text encoding.

Although you don't say it, you are likely working on Windows, and using the terminal for your program.

The problem is that Windows uses a different character encoding for your terminal than it uses for "windowed" programs, (and therefore your text editor).

That means the the code for the accented characters is the same.

First thing is understanding what is unicode and charcater encodings: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Second thing, simply change the encoding of your text editor to match that of the terminal - I am not sure the encoding used for Windows in Español, but in Portuguese, it is cp-852 for the terminal and latin1 for "windowed" (I'd bet it is "latin1" for Spanish Windows as well).

NB.> While Microsoft is stuck with these encodings from the 1980's, the rest of the World, including everything Web, uses "utf-8".  So, this encoding workaround is good for your code to work and you learn from it, but you sure should focus on using "utf-8" encoding for any thing that is destined to actually be in production.